# Efficiently querying indexed subarray using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to store in MongoDB a collection of cards for each user. A collection is basically an array of owned cards with an associated quantity.

```
Collection {
    user: ...,
    cards: [ {cardId: 133, qty: 3}, {cardId: 22, qty: 1} ]
}
```

I'm building an API with `node.js` and `mongoose` where I receive a request in the form of `[ {cardId: 133, qty: 2}, {cardId: 111, qty: 4} ]`.

Now I need to either create the card entry in the `cards` array if it doesn't exist or update the quantity if it is already there.

I need to do this efficiently as collections may contain thousands of cards so I came up with this `Schema`:

```
var OwnedCard = new Schema({
  cardId: { type: String, index: true, required: true},
  qty: { type: Number, required: true}
});

var Collection = new Schema({
    userId: { type: String, index: true },
    cards: [OwnedCard]
});
```

I'm not sure however how to take advantage of the `index` on `cardId` to quickly locate and update (or create if missing) cards in the subarray

Essentially, for each `{ cardId: ..., qty: xxx }` in request => find/update, or create the right entry in the cards array.

So far I have (to locate the collection of the user):

```
Collection.findOne({userId: userId}, function (err, collection) {
    var cards = collection.cards; // the cards
});
```

But I don't want to filter through them as a Javascript object since it doesn't take advantage of the index and might be slow, and instead look for a way to get mongo to retrieve the individual card entry quickly.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?